# How to parse nested json obiect

Tags: android, json, parsing, object, nested

I've this json:

`{"data": [{"name" "category" "id" "picture":{"data":{"url":}}}]`

My difficulty is how to parse the picture field. I tried with this code:

```
  public class JSONParser {
        public List<HashMap<String,Object>> parse(JSONObject jObject){      
            JSONArray jGames = null;
                try {       
                    jGames = jObject.getJSONArray("data");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return getGames(jGames);
            }       
            private List<HashMap<String, Object>> getGames(JSONArray jGames){
                int gameCount = jGames.length();
                List<HashMap<String, Object>> gameList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
                HashMap<String, Object> game = null;    
                for(int i=0; i<gameCount;i++){
                    try {
                        game = getGame((JSONObject)jGames.get(i));
                        gameList.add(game);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return gameList;
            }
            private HashMap<String, Object> getGame(JSONObject jGame){
                HashMap<String, Object> game = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                String gameName = "";
                String logo="";
                String user = "";           
                try {
                    gameName = jGame.getString("name");
                    logo = jGame.getString("logo_url");
                    user = jGame.getString("daily_active_users");
                    String details ="Utenti attivi : " + user + "\n";
                    game.put("name", gameName);
                    game.put("logo_url", R.drawable.icon);
                    game.put("logo_path", logo);
                    game.put("details", details);
                } catch (JSONException e) {         
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }       
                return game;
            }
        }
```

Comment: And the error/problem is?

Comment: Above posted is invalid json..Check in http://www.jsonlint.com

Answer (score 0):

this tutorial will help you [Android JSON Parsing Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Comment: I tried with: for(int i = 0; i < jGames.length(); i++){
    JSONObject c = jGames.getJSONObject(i);

                JSONObject picture = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PICTURE);
                
   }but nothing.